# How to solve this hard disk error while installing ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-systems

I was installing Ubuntu and selected erase disk and install option as I wanted to replace windows but this error occurred and now I don't have any **OS** installed.

[image: esized)]

Comment: I would get the hardware test application from the computer manufacturer and test the hard drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This output says nearly nothing. I suggest to boot from a diagnostic CD or USB stick, like systemRescueCD. Then run a short selftest with **smartctl** on the hard disks. Examine the result to see if there are severe errors. The next step is to run **fdisk** in order to see if the disk is partitioned well.

Further, test the inserted CD or DVD medium:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/my_CD
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/my_CD
find  /mnt/my_CD -type f -print -exec cp '{}' /dev/null ';'
```